Seeking optimization modelling problems involving non-continuous or non-interval defined functions for teaching
The optimization problems generated by modeling (such as the classic box problem) present in differential and integral calculus books usually  generate continuous functions defined on intervals. I am looking for examples of optimization problems via modeling that generate non-continuous functions or functions not defined on intervals.

Which “classic box problem”?

@NickC: I'm guessing, like, "Find the maximum volume tray [lidless box] you can make from a 12 x 12 sheet of cardboard" from first semester calculus.

@NickC, this one: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/boxanim/boxAnimation.htm

Why?  For students in what context?  The whole point of those problems in calculus classes is to help to teach students to use the tools used in calculus classes.  Non-differentiable examples are not germane.  There are other tools for optimization, but they are generally taught in the contexts where it makes sense to teach them.  In what context are you teaching, and why aren't the tools from calculus the right tools to be using?

Upon further reflection, I don't think that this question, in its current state, is a good fit for this site.  This is a question and answer site for mathematics educators.   Questions here should be asked in the context of education, and it is incumbent on the asker to explain what they are teaching and how the requested examples are going to be used in the classroom.  Until these issues can be clarified, I have closed the question.

@XanderHenderson - Did any other users flag this post as off-topic?

@NickC I discussed it with Sue.  She was in agreement that this question needs work.

So decision to close by authority, not community.

Discontinuous Function Example.
Suppose you want to sell custom T-shirts to support your club. You know that to sell $x$ tees, you will need to price the tees at $d(x)$ dollars per tee (provide some negative-slope, continuous demand curve). However, the cost per tee when you order x tees, $c(x)$, is a weakly decreasing step function in how many tees you order (many custom bulk ordering sites have this price model). Maximize profit, $p(x) = x\cdot(d(x)-c(x))$.
I made some weakly plausible functions for d(x) and c(x) and, by playing with the functions, you can make the maximum value occur inside an interval or at the endpoint of an interval! You can also make the maximum nonexistent, if you're mean.

Noncompact Interval Example
(Okay, this one is tricky, but it's a true example.)
The probability density a hydrogen atom's electron is observed at radius $r$ from the nucleus is given by $c r^2 e^{-r}$, where $c$ is a constant and $r$ is expressed in atomic units of distance (1 AU $\approx$ 53 pm). Find the radius at which an electron is most likely to be observed, that is, the radius with the maximum probability.
The function looks like this! (Source:This page about electron orbitals, by The OrbitronTM. )

The nice thing about this problem is that the justification that the function actually reaches its global maximum at this point can be done via a straightforward "first derivative test," illustrating the value of different forms of reasoning for identifying global extrema.

I'll note here that implicit in this question is a side note about the extreme value theorem.  The primary reason we avoid discontinuous functions in calc 1 optimization is that the distinction between maximum and supremum is not something we expect students to understand yet, and we want to teach the extreme value theorem which states that the maximum and minimum of a continuous function on a closed, bounded interval always exists; and furthermore that if the function is differentiable, it must occur at a critical point or endpoint of the interval.
Discontinuous functions and/or non-compact intervals serve to muddy the waters, in a way that students are not often mathematically mature enough to analyze yet.

One possible direction is to build an example using the ideas behind amplitude modulation (AM). Let's take our modulating signal to be a discontinuous "on/off" square wave $\text{m}(t)$ going between 0 and 1,  and the carrier signal to be a simple cosine wave $$\text{c}(t)=A_c\cos(2\pi f_c t)$$  The AM signal is then
$$AM(t)=\left(1+\frac{m(t)}{A_c}\right)\cdot c(t)$$ So we are going to "carry the on/off message $m(t)$ with higher frequency sinusoidal carrier signal $c(t)$."
The challenge of finding extrema of the discontinuous AM signal becomes more intricate because of the discontinuities caused by the modulating signal.
Here is a plot when the "on/off" signal has frequency 2, the carrier signal has frequency 20.

